# WSO2 Identity Server - OCRA specificiation support

Tags: wso2, rfc

Does the WSO2 Identity Server comply with the [OCRA: OATH Challenge-Response Algorithm specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6287)?

I've only read that it supports [OATH-HOTP](https://www.slideshare.net/wso2.org/wso2-guest-webinar-wso2-identity-server-adding-hardware-security-module-without-breaking-the-bank) - Slide 14.